# Windows 10 firewall stops name from being resolved

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, firewall, hostname

I'm trying to set up a desktop computer for RDP over LAN. I've found that I can RDP into it when I supply its LAN IP,

[image: Connection works when using IP]

but when I supply the host's name,

[image: Connection fails when using name]

I can't connect.[image: Fail message]

Similarly, pings go through just fine using IP, but when using the desktop's name, I get "Ping request could not find host StormScout. Please check the name and try again."

When I turn off Windows Firewall on the desktop, I can ping and RDP by name just fine. And yes, I have allowed RDP through the firewall.

Finally, I can ping other computers by name from the desktop, so it (afaik) doesn't seem to be a router problem.

Comment: Make sure you have file and printer sharing enabled in the Windows Firewall, or more specifically NetBIOS. That’s the only way you’re going to resolve names on a home network.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. I turned on network discovery and file and printer sharing, and now we're in business. Would you mind making an actual answer so I can accept it?